# Caliburn Micro: Ensure that all OnDeactivates were called before app's shutdown

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro, dispose, application-shutdown

I've a WPF/Caliburn app which has a `ShellView` which includes `TabControl` where each `TabItem` corresponds to individual `ViewModel` (they all inherit `Screen`).
Some of those `ViewModels` have dispose logic implemented in `OnDeactivate`:

```
protected override void OnDeactivate(bool close)
{
    if (close)
        _disposeList.Dispose();

    base.OnDeactivate(close);
}
```

`ShellViewModel` overrides `TryClose`:

```
public override async void TryClose(bool? dialogResult = default(bool?))
{
    // some dispose logic here
    base.TryClose(dialogResult);
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // show closing message for 2 sec
        using (StartBusy(ViewModelBusyReason.Closing))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    });
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
    // Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

When app closes it only calls `OnDeactivate` on 1 or 2 VMs, then app shuts down.
How to guarantee `OnDeactivate` to be called on all VMs before app close?
I tried to add Sleep in `TryClose` and it didn't work.

And also: is there a canonical Caliburn way to implement `TryClose` on `ShellViewModel`?
I.e. do I have to call `Application.Current.Shutdown()` or `Environment.Exit(0)` or neither?

`ShellViewModel` definition:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<Screen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    public ShellViewModel(/*some params here*/)
    {
        Items.Add(Bootstrapper.Resolve<ViewModelOne>());
        Items.Add(Bootstrapper.Resolve<ViewModelTwo>());
        Items.Add(Bootstrapper.Resolve<ViewModelThree>());
        // ...more VMs here
    }
```

Comment: Does the ShellViewModel keep references to the other view models or how and where are they initialized? Can't you override the CanClose method of the ShellViewModel and dispose the child view models in there then?

Comment: @mm8: I've updated the post with VMs definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is a solution which I finally came up with:

```
// ShellViewModel
public override void TryClose(bool? dialogResult = default(bool?))
{
    _disposeList.Dispose();

    while (Items.Any())
       DeactivateItem(Items.First(), true);

    base.TryClose(dialogResult);
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

And override `OnDeactivate` in each individual VM:

```
protected override void OnDeactivate(bool close)
{
    _disposeList.Dispose();
    base.OnDeactivate(close);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call each child view model's `TryClose` method from the `ShellViewModel`'s `TryClose` method:

```
//ShellViewModel:
public override void TryClose(bool? dialogResult = null)
{
    base.TryClose(dialogResult);
    //...
    foreach (var item in Items)
        item.TryClose();
}
```

Besides, any view model that uses an `IDisposable` field should implement the `IDisposable` interface:

```
public sealed class ViewModelTwo : Screen, IDisposable
{
    ...

    public override void TryClose(bool? dialogResult = null)
    {
        Dispose();
        base.TryClose(dialogResult);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _disposeList?.Dispose();
    }
}
```